# AD single-value custom attribute returning as multi-valued in powershell

Tags: active-directory

I have created several custom attributes in a test AD environment. Each is a single-valued unicode string that I have added to the user class. The first attribute I created works as expected. When I use get-ADuser -property CusAttribute1 I get back an object with type string. Every other custom attribute I have created I get back an object with type Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.ADPropertyValueCollection.

Domain functional level 2008R2. I am able to extract the array to a string value in the select statement, but I don't understand why two attributes that were created in the same way are performing differently, and I don't want to have to extract the value from the array if I don't have to.

Get-ADuser someUser -Properties cusAttribute1,cusAttribute2 |gm

The expected result would be that cusAttribute 1 and 2 would have a type of String, but instead cusAttribute1 has a type of String and cusAttribute2 has a type of Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.ADPropertyValueCollection and is an array with one value in it.

Comment: If you use the Attributes tab in AD Users and Computers, does the editor for that attribute (when you double-click on it) show up as a multi-value editor, or a single value?

Comment: Sorry for the delayed response. When I double click on the attribute it is a single-value editor. Also, in the AD Schema snap-in all of the attributes show as Unicode String and say "This attribute is single-valued."

Comment: I really don't know then, sorry. I've never seen that before.

Comment: Does it make a difference if you are running get-aduser for customAttribute2 only, versus if you run get-aduser for customAtribute1, customAttribute2?